# When upgrading Version 1.2.1 to 1.2.2, why did the `quantity` parameter of the monitoring panel adapted to Apache IoTDB have no data?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After upgrading from Version 1.2.1 to 1.2.2 of Apache IoTDB, the original `quantity` parameter in the IoTDB metrics, that is connected to the monitoring panel adapted to IoTDB on Grafana, becomes no data. I wonder if this parameter has been renamed, or why this change happened? What do I need to switch for this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This may because the panel is not compatible because Apache IoTDB added database level monitoring. You can try to change the setting of this parameter to `sum(sum(rate(quantity_total{cluster=~\"$cluster\", nodeType=~\"$nodeType\", instance=~\" $instance\"}[1m])) by (database))`, or replaced it by `quantity_total` (the parameter that is compatible to database level).